# SQL how to join these tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database

The scenario:

I have a website which let users vote between cars which they like most. Cars are saved in the table `cars`, votes are saved in `votes` and the column country_id from the table `cars` reference to `countries` (where the carbrand comes from).

I want to show the users which country has the most votes. Simple version of the tables:

**CARS**

```
id
name
country_id
```

**Countries**

```
id
name
```

**Votes**

```
id
user_id
car_id
```

Ideally I would like to show the users the top x countries. And how many votes they all have.

**Bonus:** would it be possible to use this query for a certain user? So they see their top x with countries they voted on.

And which indexes you suggest? The votes table can grow beyond 10 million votes, the cars table can grow fast too.

Comment: sounds `LEFT JOIN` , `GROUP BY` , `COUNT(*)` can achieve your goal, isn't it ?

Comment: If the number of votes is going to grow into tens of millions of rows within a foreseeable future, you have to aggregate the votes and save them somewhere.

Comment: @mzedeler do you mean I should save the voted country_id in the table votes?

Comment: No - I'd count the votes per country and save them in the countries table and the votes per car and save them in the cars table. Note that this is redundant, but if you have millions of rows, you are most likely to get a performance issue without something like this.

Comment: @mzedeler thanks a lot, I do understand what you mean. So its possible to do a select sum (votes) ... a join with countries?

Comment: @KevinVermaat: You'd have two new fields in ``cars`` and ``countries`` named ``votes``, and then update the number of votes using a background job or a trigger, so getting the number of votes for a given country would simply be ``SELECT votes FROM contries WHERE id=<country id>`` - one single row, no aggregates.

Comment: @mzedeler Thanks a lot, I did work on this last 20 minutes and I succeeded. But I could not use a trigger. I created a stored procedure which calculates sum(voted_on) from cars left join countries. The results I loop and every row I update the countries table column total_votes. The reason why I use this rather than a trigger is because I like the fact that the stored procedure run each x time instead of firing a trigger every DML since a lot of updates are going on. :)

Comment: Yes. Using a trigger will result in a large load when adding votes to the votes table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can achieve this with a `LEFT JOIN` query and `GROUP BY` aggregate function

```
SELECT COUNT(a.id) as total_votes, c.name as country_name
FROM Votes a
LEFT JOIN CARS b
ON a.car_id = b.id
LEFT JOIN Countries c
ON b.country_id = c.id
GROUP BY b.name, c.name
ORDER BY total_votes DESC
```

Comment: group by can consist of c.name, b.name as a country can have many cars voted

Comment: @fabio, i do not understand the last part of the query :/ ON user_id = c.id, wouldn't that check if the user_id the the same as country id?

Comment: @Kevin sorry my bad, i fixed it

Comment: i think c.id = b.country_id in fabio's query

Comment: also added to this query can be a WHERE clause , which solves the BONUS part of this question i.e WHERE a.user_id = x , where x is the user id

Comment: @Fabio thanks man ;) figured it out at same time hehe, pretty new to SQL joins :)

Answer (score 1):

Indexes on Cars.CountryID, Votes.UserID and Votes.CarID would seem reasonable.  As mzedler suggested though, when you get up to tens of millions, aggregates can be a bad idea.

There are number of ways of addressing that, triggers, a cache, or adding date voted to votes, so you break down the number of records you have to count in one go. e.g cache votes daily and then just query those made since midnight and then sum them.